# How to Pass List<int> parameter to SOAP UI on a Web Api C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, soapui

I have a WebApi with something like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(List<int> Ids)
{
    //do some stuff with the List
}
```

I don't know if I have to do it POST because of that list or if I can use Get and recieve a list of int, I'm using SOAP UI here is a SS.

[image: SOAP UI Screen shot]

Comment: Try sending `,` separated values `1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the code is concerned, you should consider the following...

FromUri:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetListFromUri([FromUri] List<int> ids)
{
   //do some stuff with the List
}
```

FromBody:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetListFromBody([FromBody] List<int> ids)
{
   //do some stuff with the List
}
```

Also have a look at how parameter binding works in Web Api.

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api